# Finding the worst case of quick sort O(N^2)

Tags: arrays, sorting, time-complexity, quicksort

I am currently trying to find an ordering for the array: {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7} such that when we choose the middle element as our pivot it yields a quadratic time complexity.
How will i make an ordering to this array such that it becomes O(N^2)? Pivot must be the middle element.

Comment: Surely you could just try a few things and see how you do. The worst case occurs when the pivot element is always either the largest or the smallest in the subarray being worked on. So for the 1st pivot, if the array were {2, 3, 4, 1, 5, 6, 7} would accomplish that. Now you've got to make it work for the next subarray, and then the next, etc.

Comment: I understand this method, but how does this actually yield a quadratic time complexity? what is the math behind it?

Comment: You can work through it by hand, but basically you have to compare n elements on the first pass, then n-1 elements on the second pass, then n-2,... then 2 elements, and finally 1 element. n + (n-1) + (n-2) + ... +2 +1 = n*(n+1)/2 = O(n^2)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Lomuto partition scheme where pivot is not included in next level of recursion, and that left middle is used for even number of elements:

```
array                pivot
6 4 2 1 3 5 7        1
6 4 2 3 5 7          2
6 4 3 5 7            3
6 4 5 7              4
6 5 7                5
6 7                  6
7
```